# ASP.NET validation missing something?

Tags: asp.net, validation, requiredfieldvalidator

I usually don't resort to posting questions that seem simple, but this one has me stumped.

I have a text box that is a required field, and when I click submit I want to validate the text box.

Here is my code:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" CssClass="textboxField" MaxLength="45"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:LinkButton ID="btnAdd" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" >Add +</asp:LinkButton>

<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="reqName" ControlToValidate="txtName" ErrorMessage="Name is required." runat="server" />
```

Everything here looks correct to me syntax wise, but for some reason I am not seeing an error message when the text box is blank and the add button is clicked. Any suggestions?

EDIT: Page directive

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPages/SiteMaster.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="CodeBehind.aspx.cs" Inherits="Site.Page" %>
```

Comment: Can you show the Page directive?

Comment: Don't you need a validation summary somewhere on the page to display errors?

Comment: No, usually it will just show the error where the required field validator is declared.

Comment: I think your browser's javascript is disabled!